# How to Gaussian Fit Histogram?

Tags: python, pandas, curve-fitting, gaussian

I have a `pandas.DataFrame` of the form

```
index     ABC       

1         -40       
2         -30       
3         -30       
4         -20       
5         -20       
6         -10       
7         -10       
8         -10      
9          0      
10         0       
11         0       
12         0       
13         10       
14         10       
15         10      
16         10      
17         20     
18         20      
19         20       
20         30       
21         40
```

I want to do data analysis on 'ABC'.

1. Draw a histogram for 'ABC'.
2. Gaussian fitting the histogram.
3. Measure the full width at half maximum (FWHM).
   I would like to proceed in the above order. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

### 1. Draw histogram

```
_, bins, _ = plt.hist(data, 20, density=1, alpha=0.5)
```

[image]

### 2. Gaussian fitting

```
_, bins, _ = plt.hist(data, 20, density=1, alpha=0.5)
mu, sigma = scipy.stats.norm.fit(data)
best_fit_line = scipy.stats.norm.pdf(bins, mu, sigma)
plt.plot(bins, best_fit_line)
```

[image]

### 3. FWHM

```
x = data.index.values
y = np.array(data['ABC'])

def lin_interp(x, y, i, half):
    return x[i] + (x[i+1] - x[i]) * ((half - y[i]) / (y[i+1] - y[i]))

def half_max_x(x, y):
    half = max(y)/2.0
    signs = np.sign(np.add(y, -half))
    zero_crossings = (signs[0:-2] != signs[1:-1])
    zero_crossings_i = np.where(zero_crossings)[0]
    return [lin_interp(x, y, zero_crossings_i[0], half),
            lin_interp(x, y, zero_crossings_i[1], half)]
hmx = half_max_x(x,y)
fwhm = hmx[1] - hmx[0]
```

Comment: thank you very much.
I have a few more questions.
1. When I set the Y-axis, I want to set it to the cumulative number instead of density=1.
2. I think FWHM will vary depending on bins. I want to plot a histogram according to the bin size.